# MediaWiki alter default user signature

Tags: mediawiki-extensions

I've tried finding some info on this (found none), so trying the sages of SO before giving up.

I'm modifying Extension:AuthRemoteuser for a local SSO solution.

It would be a nice touch to change the default signature to a string other than the user name (which is an integer string at the moment for us), e g. Real Name.

Hoping someone knows the function call  to set signature so that I'd be able to do something akin to:

```
$mySwellSignature = "Foobar";
$usr->setSignature($mySwellSignature); //This is what I'm looking for ;_;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise the [[MediaWiki:Signature]] page on your wiki ([see system message documentation](https://translatewiki.net/wiki/MediaWiki:Signature/qqq)) to alter how `~~~~` and `~~~` are parsed.

If you want to pass additional parameters, like real name, you can do so by altering the line(s) in the parser where this message is used; or by introducing a parser function which you can then use on [[MediaWiki:Signature]] like e.g. [UserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserFunctions) (only an example; I'm not recommending this extension).